# When sending transactions with JSON-RPC: Integer type must have numerical suffix?

Tags: transactions, json-rpc

As the picture shows, when sending transactions with jsonrpc, I use the `call_with_transaction` function. But it tells me that there is something wrong with my way of asserting the arguments (that "1")

```
AssertionError: Integer type must have numerical suffix
```

[image]

What does that mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that there's some problem with the client.py file in the ethjsonrpc module. in this example the type of the argument should be further specified like "uint8" and to do so it will pop a new problem claiming that "can not parse the number". To fix this problem, you need modify the clent.py a little, changing all the "hex(something)" function to "'0x'+format(something,'x')" will help, may this help you.